# SHELL : Output not as expected

Tags: shell

I'm doing this homework below and I do have a question about my program :

Write a shell script that copies files as described below. A postfix should be transferred as a command line parameter. For each file from the current directory where the specified postfix fits, the user should be asked whether the file should be saved. If the answer is yes, the file should be copied into the backup directory. The directory should be created if it does not exist.

This is what I did :

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
  echo "Usage : prog.sh <POSTFIX> " >&2
  exit 1
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
 usage
fi

list=$(ls)

for name in $list; do

  case $name in

  *.$@)
    printf "Do you want to save the file ?\n"
    read answer

    case $answer in
     Yes|yes|y)
      ls backup 2>/dev/null || mkdir backup
      mv $name backup
      ;;
     No|no|n);;
    esac ;;
  esac
done
```

Assuming I have these folders below : ( that will be moved to backup directory)

```
bar.txt foobar.txt foo.txt mbar.txt
```

This was my output :

```
Do you want to save the file ? 
y
Do you want to save the file ? 
y
bar.txt                           // Why is it printing the file during the output ?
Do you want to save the file ? 
y
bar.txt  foobar.txt               // ??
Do you want to save the file ? 
y                                 
bar.txt  foobar.txt  foo.txt     // ??
```

I know that I can write it this way (instead of  `ls backup 2>/dev/null || mkdir backup`)

```
  if [ ! -d backup ] ; then
           mkdir backup
   fi
```

but I want to know why is my program printing the files that will moved to backup during the output ?

Comment: This part is troubling me: `case $name in *.$@)` -- what parameters do you pass to the script?

Comment: This: `list=$(ls); for name in $list; do` should be replaced with `for name in *; do`

Comment: @glennjackman: it's run like that: `script txt`

Comment: @glennjackman : ./prog.sh txt (for example)

Comment: Are you limited to /bin/sh or can you use bash?

Comment: Yea bash is possible too . We're allowed to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
ls backup 2>/dev/null
```

you only redirect stderr but not stdout. You should do this:

```
ls backup >/dev/null 2>&1 || mkdir backup
```

or just:

```
mkdir -p backup
```

You should also take care of all warnings issued by shellcheck:

```
$ shellcheck ./p.sh

In ./p.sh line 18:
            read answer
            ^--^ SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.


In ./p.sh line 24:
                    mv $name backup
                       ^---^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean:
                    mv "$name" backup

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2162 -- read without -r will mangle backs...
```

Comment: Very helpful thank you . Good to know that there is a shellcheck feature that checks the warnings. I  didn't know about that .

Answer (score 4):

Because of you do `ls backup 2>/dev/null` for every file moved to `backup` directory, next `ls` will show them;

by the way, your whole script can be replaced with single `rsync` command below:

```
rsync --include='*.{txt,csv,xyz}' /path/to/source/* /path/to/backup/
```

see [`man rsync`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) for details and also how you can delete after sync.

Answer (score 1):

If bash is allowed, I would do this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "usage: ${0##*/} extension ..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

dir=./backup
mkdir -p "$dir"

# if the script is called like `script.sh foo bar baz`
# then $pattern is `@(*foo|*bar|*baz)`
pattern=$(
    set -- "${@/#/*}"
    IFS='|'
    echo "@($*)"
)

shopt -s nocasematch

for file in *; do       
    # right-hand side is specifically unquoted
    if [[ "$file" == $pattern ]]; then
        read -p "Move file '$file'? [y/N] " ans
        if [[ "$ans" == Y* ]]; then
            mv -i -v "$file" "$dir"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Since this is a assignment, do some research on any part you don't understand before you ask specific questions here. The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is a good place to start.